# How to represent p-adic expansion of $a^{-1}$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

I'm trying to find represent expansion of $a^{-1}$, if 
$$a = a_{r} \cdot p^{r} + a_{r+1} \cdot p^{r+1} +...$$

I have tried get solution supposing that $a \cdot a^{-1} = 1$, but stucked.  I don't even see any pattern, for example with $p = 3$:

$$3 = 1 \cdot 3^{1} $$

$$\frac{1}{3} = 1 \cdot 3^{-1}$$

While

$$2 = 2 \cdot 3^{0}$$ $$\frac{1}{2} = 2 \cdot 3^{0} + 1 \cdot 3^{1} + 1 \cdot 3^{2} + ...$$

And

$$-3 = 2 \cdot 3^{1} + 2 \cdot 3^{2} + 2 \cdot 3^{3} + ...  $$ $$-\frac{1}{3} = 2 \cdot 3^{-1} + 2 \cdot 3^{0} + 2 \cdot 3^{1}$$

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method of finding a p-adic expansion to a rational number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186967/method-of-finding-a-p-adic-expansion-to-a-rational-number)

Comment: Perhaps there isn't a simple rule to cover all expansions.  You might benefit from looking at a number as $p^ku$ where $u$ is a $p$-adic unit.  Then in your last two examples you'd be considering $3\cdot (-1)$ and $3^{-1}\cdot (-1)$  The case of $1/2$ can be understood as an example of a geometric seies.

Comment: One kind of hacky way is, after removing the power of p from a to leave a unit, you can use Euler's theorem to compute to k digits of accuracy, $a^{\varphi(p^k)-1} \equiv a^{-1} \mod p^k$.